# How to Cross Compile a Rust application from Linux to Windows including the ring lib without docker

Tags: linux, windows, rust, cross-compiling

I wrote an application with Rust, which is working quite fine on Windows and Linux using `cargo run` and `cargo build`.

To have only one system capable of compiling for both targets `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` and `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` I set up a Ubuntu 22.04 minimum server installation with these additional commands

```
apt update
apt upgrade -y
apt install curl build-essential gcc make -y
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs > ~/rustup.sh
cd ~
chmod u+x rustup.sh
./rustup.sh -y
. ~/.cargo/env
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --toolchain stable
rustup target add x86_64-pc-windows-msvc --toolchain stable
```

Then switching to the application directory

```
cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

works fine and produces the artifact as expected. But

```
cargo build --release --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

failes with the error message

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.20`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/test/backend/target/release/build/ring-3857f585b2d049fe/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  TARGET_CC = None
  CC = None
  CROSS_COMPILE = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")

  --- stderr
  running "cc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-m64" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "/GS" "/Gy" "/EHsc" "/GR-" "/Zc:wchar_t" "/Zc:forScope" "/Zc:inline" "/Zc:rvalueCast" "/sdl" "/Wall" "/wd4127" "/wd4464" "/wd4514" "/wd4710" "/wd4711" "/wd4820" "/wd5045" "/Ox" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "/Fo/test/backend/target/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/release/build/ring-e02c6ae3738202e7/out/aes_nohw.obj" "crypto/fipsmodule/aes/aes_nohw.c"
  cc: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
  thread 'main' panicked at 'execution failed', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/build.rs:656:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

As stated by [the ring library](https://github.com/briansmith/ring/blob/main/BUILDING.md) I need to

```
When you build ring for a target that is different than the one you are using for the build process you need to install the rust tool chain and a C/C++ compiler that can produce binaries for the intended target.

Besides the required dependencies you need to set the environment variables TARGET_CC and TARGET_AR to the full path of the cross-compiler and the cross-archiver respectively.
```

Still I was not able to figure out which package to install and how to set the mentioned variables `TARGET_CC` and `TARGET_AR` in order to make the build working.

Is there a way how to cross-compile a Rust-Application for Windows under Ubuntu Linux 22.04 without using a VM or Docker-Container with a Windows installation?

Comment: Just as a general remark: Looks like there are also other libraries that have difficulties beeing cross-compiled like `libsqlite3-sys v0.24.2` ... which failed also with a strange error `error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is lib.exe installed?` ...